# Why does the reference count of an object initialized in Swift playground starts with 2, not 1?

Tags: swift, reference, initialization, automatic-ref-counting

[image]

Can anyone confirm that why the reference count of object car is "2" not one?
Although when this object is set to nil, its deallocating it properly.
(i missed one line of code in image where i am doing car = nil , to check deallocation)

Comment: @Hamish Here, deinit is working as expected....

Comment: You *cannot* rely on retain count, it is mostly useless (look up "when to use retain count" ...)  The compiler may even add retain/release calls around the *call* to the  CFGetRetainCount() function.

Comment: When to use retain count: http://sdarlington.github.io/

Comment: Try this one in a compiled project: `do { let car = Vehicle(); let x = CFGetRetainCount(car); print(x) }` – It prints "2" in Debug mode and "1" in Release mode. So it really depends on whether the compiler inserts or eliminates retain/release cycles. In other words, the value doesn't tell you anything.